# Java - execute stored procedure

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, procedure

I need to execute procedure from sql using java.

I have call my procedure in sql management like exec MyProcedure and works well.
But when I use it in java code I get error :

> The statement did not return a result set.

This is my code:

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement cs = null;
    Connection conn = DbM.dbConnect();

    try {
        cs = conn.prepareStatement("exec MyProcedure ?,?,?");
        cs.setEscapeProcessing(true);
        cs.setQueryTimeout(90);

        cs.setString(1, "1");
        cs.setString(2, "2019-01-01");
        cs.setString(3, "2019-02-02");

        rs = cs.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<Data> listaObjectX = new ArrayList<Data>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Data to = new Data();
            to.setEmployeNo(rs.getString(1));
            to.setValidFrom(rs.getDate(2));
            to.setValidTo(rs.getDate(3));
            listaObjectX.add(to);
        } 
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println("Error al ejecutar SQL"+ se.getMessage());
        se.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error al ejecutar SQL: " + se.getMessage());

    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            cs.close();
            conn.close();;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When run code I got error:

> The statement did not return a result set.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

If I put   cs= conn.prepareStatement("exec MyProcedure (?,?,?)");
I get error

Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

Comment: Shouldn't there be parentheses around the arguments? What database are you using?

Comment: https://thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/

Comment: I use SQL database.

Comment: @stack SQL is a language, not a database engine. Maybe you are referring to SQL Server from Microsoft?

Comment: Add a println inside `rs.next()` loop and see if it executes..

Comment: microsoft sql db

Comment: @JGFMK I add println in loop but stops before loops rs = cs.executeQuery();

Answer (score 0):

If this procedure is not returning a result, you should be using execute() instead of executeQuery() which is expected to always return a ResultSet.

Comment: It's not work, show error : Change type of 'rs' to boolean

Comment: Yes, do that. Or just don't assign the result of the execute method, because it's not returning anything anyway. If you are expecting to get a ResultSet though, check your procedure if it is returning anything.

Comment: I check my procedure, returns result, but when use java i got error